# How does grouping alerts in Alertmanager?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have the same alerts with one different label and want to group it into one message in slack. Try to make group_by this label but all the same have message for every label

my alertmanager config:

```
global:
  slack_api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/'

templates:
- '/etc/alertmanager/alertmanager.tmpl'

route:
  group_by: ['alertname', 'service_name']
  repeat_interval: 10s
  group_interval: 10s
  receiver: default

  routes:
    - match:
        type: 'test_alert'
      receiver: 'slack'
      group_by: ['grouping_tag']
      group_wait: 1m
      group_interval: 10s
      continue: false

receivers:
  - name: 'slack'
    slack_configs:
      - send_resolved: true
        color: "{{ if eq .Status `firing` }}#ffe12b{{ else }}good{{ end }}"
        title: 'title'
        text: '{{ .GroupLabels.grouping_tag }}'
```

also i treid to move group config to main route, but results are the same

my prometheus alert is:

```
groups:
- name: test alert
  rules:
  - alert: test alert for my metric
    expr: sum by (grouping_tag) (rate(my_metric{}[60s])) == 0
    #for: 120s
    labels:
      severity: disaster
      resolv: true
      grouping_tag: "{{ $labels.grouping_tag }}"
      type: "test_alert"
    annotations:
      summary: "test alert title"
      description: "test text message with {{ $labels.grouping_tag }}"
```

i try to make grouping alert by label in alertmanager. But alerts are sendind single, each with different label

There was few question on stackoverflow with this question, but i can`t correct configure alertm with this advises